# Javascript/jQuery: Is there a better way to acomplish this in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, repeat

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { //Document Ready

$(".examples .example1").click(function() {

    $(".examples .example1 div").fadeToggle("slow");
    $(".examples .example1").toggleClass('focused');

});


$(".examples .example2").click(function() {

    $(".examples .example2 div").fadeToggle("slow");
    $(".examples .example2").toggleClass('focused');

});


$(".examples .example3").click(function() {

    $(".examples .example3 div").fadeToggle("slow");
    $(".examples .example3").toggleClass('focused');


});

}); // End
```

This just basically duplicates the same thing on 3 (only 2 in the example below) different
elements- Click, Toggle a div, and toggle a class.

**[Working code here](http://codepen.io/hwg/pen/kDgbj)** (Ugly and not as It appears in the site- lacking other css/less and images)

This works perfectly, but the (very small) JS person within me says that there must be a cleaner way of doing the same thing? Seems too repetitive and ugly.

Could anyone help to make this better code? (and hence me a better coder if I learn)

Comment: Your demo shows only one element with each `examplesX` class. Are there more than one for each?

Comment: How about: http://jsfiddle.net/5anxN/

Comment: @CrazyTrain No, there would be one of each number.

Comment: @harley: Then you can always use `this` to refer to the element  which received the event. If that was the only purpose for the unique numbered classes, then make it a common class instead.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I did try `this`, but it didn't seem to work so I didn't use it. Will try again in the future, thanks!

Comment: Why wrapping divs with spans?

Comment: Is there a typo in your last click function?

Comment: Heh, I didn't notice that OP was doing that. It's invalid, and the browser is going to rearrange the page, likely breaking things.

Comment: @epascarello THIS is the question here, else I would have written what you answered too.

Comment: @epascarello Yes there is, but as I hadn't added a 3rd span in the HTML, then I hadn't noticed the issue. Tahnks for the pointing out.

Comment: @undefined Moment of Madness :) Will fix when I finalise it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a common class on all of the elements. You can than use `this` to reference the element that was clicked on.

```
$(".examples>span").click(function() {   
    $(this).toggleClass('focused').find("div").fadeToggle("slow");    
});
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but look at the question: `$(".examples .example3")` takes effect on `$(".examples .example2 div")` (and not on `$(".examples .example3 div")`).

Comment: @bwoebi: I'd bet that's a copy error when creating the code example.

Comment: @epascarello I didn't downvote, but I added a different class- "NOTOGGLE" nad it ws still toggled when I clicked on it?

Comment: What do you mean NOTOGGLE? You lost me. And please answer my question about the typo under the main question so it clears up your question for other people.

Comment: @harley: Your markup is invalid, and one of your `p` elements is missing its `/` in the closing tag.

Comment: @epascarello In your answer, before you edited it, you said- if you want the span to **not** toggle then just add/change the class. I did so, making up the random class of notoggle, and it didn't make a difference. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You would need to change the selector! `$(".examples>span.yourClass")`

Comment: @epascarello Ahh. I thought you meant in the HTML. Anyways, you are awesome and have taught me to mend my ways regarding jQuery :) Thanks (Accepting answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() { //Document Ready
   $('.examples > span[class^="example"]').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('focused').children('div').fadeToggle('slow');
   });
}); // End
```

This will target a span child if `.examples` with a class name that begins with `example`. It will the toggle the `focused` class on this element before moving on the find the child `div` and toggling slow on it.

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DBHFy